# EOFError when loading list of dicts with various datatypes

Tags: python, pickle, joblib

I have list of dicts, where each dict contains multiple different items. Its used as memory replay in training process of reinforcement learning and I need to create a backup file in case something interupts that process. Each dict represents one environment step so the structure is same, only values differ.

The data types every dict contains are: *numpy.array, int, bool, string, list* of numpy arrays and *float*. Np array is preprocessed so it does contain real float numbers - no NaN or Inf.

My problem is, that I have tried multiple ways, how to store and load files and all of them behaved similarly - backup is created with no problem, but sometimes(or even not at all - simply no pattern to spot bug elsewhere) when loading it, it raises EOFError.

Maximal amount of data in list is now limited to 100k and created file is usually around 128MB.

Currently I'm trying it via pickle.dumps, but in past I have tried plain joblib dump/load and copy.deepcopy to dump.

```
def _save_backup(self, path:str, name:str) -> dict:
    file_path = path+name+'_memory.joblib'
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        serialized_mem = pickle.dumps(self._memory,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        dump(serialized_mem,f)    
    return {'memory':file_path}


def _load_backup(self, data:dict):
    if os.path.exists(data['memory']):
        with open(data['memory'], "rb") as f:
            serialized_mem = load(f)
            self._memory = pickle.loads(serialized_mem)
```

**Edit**

to answer [tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney) comment:

- load and dump are from joblib

`from joblib import dump, load
import pickle`

- idea was to serialize object into string by pickle.dumps and since it only creates string but does not save into file, I then use joblib.dump to create such file.
- error is raised indeed in `serialized_mem = load(f)`
- No exceptions are supressed during saving
- after dump the filepath is passed as dict(to maintain inheritance of baseclass) to main class, and merged with other paths of backup files like neural network, optimizer etc.
- Error file size is not deterministic - sometimes it fails before the list reaches its full capacity (100k samples) and then its ofc smaller, and sometimes error happens after for example 500k steps so the size is normal. But you lead me to remember quite an important detail... the `self._memory` is in fact of type *deque* (`from collections import deque`) (its inherited from parent and allows working with it like with list, thats why I forgot about it). And as a deque it might be a problem saving "unfull" object, which would explain the meaning of EOFError. I will do some tests and report the outcome.

Comment: What are `dump()` and `load()`? Are you double-pickling? Where is the error... on `load(f)`? Does the file look reasonably sized on failure? Are you catching and supressing exceptions that may have happened durning dump, causing an abreiviated file?

Comment: @tdelaney I have added details which you have asked for. The question about size of files gave me an idea which I will be testing.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of days without an error so I guess its fixed. At the end I used something a bit different, since I experienced `MemoryError` during saving while running 64bit python version on 32GB RAM with more than half of that available to be used.

This implementation seems to solve both `MemoryError` and `EOFError` when loading

```
def save_backup(self, path:str, name:str) -> dict:
    # save memory
    file_path = path+name+'_memory.joblib'
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        for data in list(self._memory):
            pickle.dump(data,f)  
    # save other files
    d = self._save_backup(path,name) # child class method
    # merge dicts
    d.update({'memory':file_path})
    return d


def load_backup(self, data:dict):
    # load memory
    if os.path.exists(data['memory']):
        with open(data['memory'], "rb") as f:
            self._memory.clear()
            while True:
                try:
                    self._memory.append(pickle.load(f))
                except EOFError:
                    break
    # load others
    self._load_backup(data) # child class method
```